# How do I fix 'WriteMessage: Bad file descriptor' of screen -r name?

Tags: gnu-screen

When I try to resume a screen session with

```
$ screen -r name
```

I get

```
WriteMessage: Bad file descriptor
```

How can I fix that? (Ideally being able to resume the screen, but at least remove it if resuming is not possible)

The problem why it occurs might be that the SSH connection was interrupted.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

1. Find the process's pid by running `screen -R`
2. Use `screen -r <pid>` instead of `screen -r <name>`

If the screen didn't detach from previous ssh session, you might also need to kill dead sshd process.

Comment: To clarify, the PID is the first series of digits (prior to `.`) in the names output from `screen R`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to detach all screens with `screen -D`. I had attached the screen with

`screen -R screen-name-here`

To detach, I needed to specify the screen name:

`screen -D screen-name-here`